# Is it possible to use resource files (.resx) with Compile-time logging source generation?

Tags: c#, .net, microsoft.extensions.logging

I have an application that is using simple `_logger.LogInformation()` api with resource files (.resx).

```cs
_logger.LogInformation(LogResource.LogText);
```

Is it possible to rewrite this code to use the `[LoggerMessageAttribute]` with resource files?

As I know attribute constructors expect constant expressions, but .resx helpers are static, so this code doesn't work:

```cs
internal static partial class LoggerExtensions
{
    [LoggerMessage(Level = LogLevel.Information, Message = LogResource.LogText)]
    public static partial void LogText(this ILogger logger);
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by log with resource files, could you share a  document to the `LogResource.LogText`? I can't find anything related to that.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/create-resource-files#resources-in-resx-files

Comment: No, I get that, but what is the particular problem you are facing with resource files and logging here, I don't understand how they are related.

Comment: The log message is stored in a .resx file (LogResource.resx with LogText key).  Visual Studio and Rider are able to generate a static helper class (LogResource.Designer.cs) that exposes the strings stored in the resx file as static properties (LogResource.LogText).